Register reading error: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)
I have an Mass Flow Controller (voegtlin red-y smart series) where I want to set the gas volume flow and also read the current gas volume flow and the temperature. The communication is via Modbus RTU. I managed to connect the MFC with the right parameters.
It's conncected to my PC so no Ethernet usage.
import logging
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder, BinaryPayloadBuilder
from datetime import datetime

# Configure the logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Establish connection to the Modbus device
client = ModbusClient(method="rtu", port='COM3', stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=57600, timeout=2)
logger.info("Establishing connection: %s", client.connect())


def set_gas_flow_set_point(client, set_point):
    try:
        # You can set the set point for the volume flow here
        set_point_gas_flow = 2

        # Code to set the set point for the volume flow
        set_point_registers = set_gas_flow_set_point(client, set_point_gas_flow)

        # Code to set the set point for the gas flow
        builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(byteorder=Endian.Big)
        builder.add_32bit_float(set_point)
        client.write_registers(0x0006, builder.to_registers(), unit=2)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error setting set point: %s", e)


def read_current_measurements(client):
    try:
        # Read gas flow
        gas_flow_result = client.read_holding_registers(0x0000, 2, unit=2)
        if gas_flow_result.isError():
            logger.error("Error reading gas flow: %s", gas_flow_result)
            return None, None

        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(gas_flow_result.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
        current_gas_flow = decoder.decode_32bit_float()

        # Read temperature
        gas_temp_result = client.read_holding_registers(0x0002, 2, unit=2)
        if gas_temp_result.isError():
            logger.error("Error reading gas temperature: %s", gas_temp_result)
            return None, None

        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(gas_temp_result.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
        gas_temperature = decoder.decode_32bit_float()

        return current_gas_flow, gas_temperature

    except ModbusIOException as e:
        logger.error("Modbus communication error: %s", e)
        return None, None

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unknown error reading measurements: %s", e)
        return None, None


current_gas_flow, gas_temperature = read_current_measurements(client)

if current_gas_flow is not None and gas_temperature is not None:
    logger.info("Current gas flow: %s", current_gas_flow)
    logger.info("Gas temperature: %s", gas_temperature)
else:
    logger.error("Error reading measurements.")

client.close()


That's the answer in my terminal that I get when I try to run the code:
INFO:main:Establishing connection: True
ERROR:main:Error reading gas flow: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)
ERROR:main:Error reading measurements.
It seems that my code is not able to read the registers. I used the logger to get a more specific error notification. Without the logger command I always got the error: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
I'm pretty new to that Python and Modbus thing so please try to explain the corrections as good as you can that you are suggesting.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Are you sure your wiring and comms parameters are correct (these devices use 9600 8n1 by default). I would suggest testing with a known good tool (e.g. mbpoll/modpoll) to ensure the basics are right before writing custom code. Note that creating the client does not actually result in any communication with the MFC (first comms will be read_holding_registers(0x0000, 2, unit=2)).

Hi, thanks for the answer. Sorry I forgot to mention that somebody has changed the baudrade to that number and the slave address to "2". Well I can say when I define the client right I got the answer that the connection was successful.

If you change the baud rate to 9600 in your code I believe the connect will still succeed (but it will not actually communicate if the settings are wrong). Depending on the version of pymodbus unit=2 may need to change to slave=2 (see here).

Oh my god, thank you so much. That was the mistake. I just had to change "unit" to slave. Now there's no error anymore.
I had to do some adjustments for the set gasflow and now the device is doing what it's supposed to.

Pymodbus v2 used the parameter unit to identify the slave as seen in this example
rr = client.read_coils(1, 1, unit=UNIT)

In version 3 the parameter changed as shown in this example
rr = client.read_coils(1, 1, slave=SLAVE)

In the initial V3 release the unit parameter was still processed (a warning was raised). However in subsequent releases this has changed (and I believe unit is now ignored).
Note that the Modbus RTU spec uses the term "Slave" whereas the TCP spec changes this to "Unit" (for effectively the same field).
